# Get executive workflow name - CRM 4

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have started to write a workflow assembly for CRM 4.0 that should kill any other running workflows with the given name (in my case, all other workflows except him self).

```
ConditionExpression ce = new ConditionExpression();
ce.AttributeName = "name";
ce.Values = new Object[]{this.WorkflowName}; // Dependency Property
query.EntityName = EntityName.asyncoperation.ToString();
```

Has anyone an idea, how to get the current workflow name out of the IContextService or something like that?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit of a long way around, but you could use `IWorkflowContext.AsyncOperationId` to get the ID of the current workflow.

Using that ID you can then query the `asyncoperation` to get the `name` of the workflow.

Comment: Yes right.. But I made it now customizable with the dependency property as parameter :-) But thx for answering!